# Why can't I retreive my data? (Flutter-Rest API)

Tags: json, rest, flutter, jwt

I've been trying to retreive data from my database using REST API. There are not error in my code but there is no data shown in my emulator and it keeps showing circular progress indicator (that means no data)

Is this because of token that I want to get from shared preferences? or something else?

This is my getToken code :

```
    String token;

  Future<String> getToken() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    String token = prefs.getString("token");
    return token;
  }
```

This is my ShowPost code :

```
Future<List<Post>> showPosts() async {
    String token = await getToken();

    var data = await http.get(
      "https://api-wisapedia.herokuapp.com/posts?sortBy=createdAt:desc",
      headers: {HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: 'Bearer $token'},
    );
    var dataDecoded = json.decode(data.body);

    List<Post> posts = List();
    dataDecoded.forEach((post) {
      post.add(post["destination"], post["owner"], post["image"]);
    });
    return posts;
  }
```

And this is my body code :

```
FutureBuilder(
            future: showPosts(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                return ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return Card(
                        color: Color(0xFFE1F5FE),
                        child: Column(
                          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            ListTile(
                              leading: Image(
                                  image: AssetImage('lib/images/pantai.jpg')),
                              title: Text(snapshot.data[index].title),
                              subtitle: Text(snapshot.data[index].destination),
                            ),
                            ButtonTheme.bar(
                              // make buttons use the appropriate styles for cards
                              child: ButtonBar(
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  FlatButton(
                                    child: const Text('DETAILS'),
                                    onPressed: () {
                                      Navigator.push(
                                        context,
                                        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
                                          return DetailPost();
                                        }),
                                      );
                                    },
                                  ),
                                  FlatButton(
                                    child: const Text('JOIN'),
                                    onPressed: () {
                                      /* ... */
                                    },
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      );
                    });
              } else {
                return Align(
                  alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                );
              }
            })
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

remove the () in the future parameter of the future builder 
`future : showPosts`  not `future :showPosts()`.

**Edit** :

replace `FutureBuilder` with `FutureBuilder<List<Post>>` and `AsyncSnapshot` with `AsyncSnapshot<List<Post>>` to specify the data type of the incoming data.

Comment: I've tried this but it makes my code error :
 Error: The argument type 'Future<List<Post>> Function()' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Future<dynamic>'.
Try changing the type of the parameter, or casting the argument to 'Future<dynamic>'.
            future: showPosts,
                    ^